# Return entity without database Nelmio Symfony

Tags: symfony, api-doc, nelmioapidocbundle

I use Nelmio to generate automatically my api doc. I would like to return an object in responseMap which is a simple class (entity without a database associated) like this :

```
/**
* @ApiDoc(
*  description = "Get informations from user.",
*   responseMap = {
*     200 = { "\AppBundle\Entity\MyUserInfos" },
*   },
* )
*
* @Rest\View(statusCode=Response::HTTP_OK)
* @Rest\Get("/my_user_infos")
*/ 
public function getMyUserInfosAction(Request $request) {
...
}


namespace AppBundle\Entity;

/**
 * MyUserInfos
 */
class MyUserInfos
{
 /**
 * @var string
 */
private $username;

/**
 * @var string
 */
private $email;

+getters and setters
}
```

But response object is not displayed in my api doc. Can anyone help me ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the leading backslash on you class name

```
/**
* @ApiDoc(
*  description = "Get informations from user.",
*   responseMap = {
*     200 = { "AppBundle\Entity\MyUserInfos" },
*   },
* )
*
* @Rest\View(statusCode=Response::HTTP_OK)
* @Rest\Get("/my_user_infos")
*/ 
public function getMyUserInfosAction(Request $request) {
...
}
```

See:https://github.com/nelmio/NelmioApiDocBundle/blob/2d70b0802144fd2c868783c46fa1be4a774967d4/Resources/doc/swagger-support.rst#multiple-response-models

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately it does not work better. I tried with or without bracket but no changes. Is it possible to use an entity without ORM link ?

Comment: You definitely don't need any ORM here. Can you see the response map in your ApiDoc and the proporties are empty? If you don't use the ORM you may have to add the Serializer annotations.

Comment: I see the response map ("Return" section with code 200 inside) but properties are empty. I have serializer annotation enabled (default serializer). But no success.

Comment: Does you MyUserInfos proporties gave the annotations? The bundle must have informations like ORM or Serializer annotations to know which proporties are available.

Comment: Ok. So i had annotations like @Type("string") in all properties, then enabled JMS serializer, and now MyUserInfos properties are displayed in api doc. That was what you were thinking ?

Comment: Yes, my problem is solved. Thanks a lot for your help.